# How to insert an element as a first child inside other element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have `Div` that it contains some other elements like `<p>`,`<ul>`,... How I can Add a `Div` as first child od my main div?

consider this tags:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
    <p>....
    <ul>...
    <span>....
</div>
```

I want it become:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
    <div id="newDiv"></div>
    <p>....
    <ul>...
    <span>....
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#MainDiv').prepend('<div id="newDiv"></div>');
```

Comment: Does `appent` insert tag as first child?

Comment: No, the other way around, `append` will insert the element at the end of the parent container, and `prepend` will insert the element at the start. :)

Comment: @Kerezo: Documentation *does exist*. You just have to read it: http://api.jquery.com/append/ (and http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).